# How to add multiple rows into checklist section in Microsoft Planner Online?

Tags: microsoft-planner

I have created some tasks in task.office.com. For each tasks, there will be many checklists, each of which corresponds to a row in Excel. I wonder if there is a way that I can copy these rows and paste to a task in the checklist section?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Huy[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can provide feedback or request features through the feedback portal. This item seems like it is asking for the same feature:
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/e2e1fc5c-eaa9-ec11-a81c-000d3a7ce453